# Custom font Fira Sans works on iOS 8 but not on iOS 7

Tags: ios, fonts, customization

I want to use Fira Sans in my iOS app. Did everything as explained here - http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

It works correctly on iOS 8

But the font won't render on iOS 7 and is giving me errors like:

Error: FiraSans-Medium: FT_Load_Glyph failed: error 139.

And a lot of them

Comment: I did re-download the file, and it worked out. It does not sound like a solution, though - could've been some other random bug. If you confirm this - please, respond here with this solution, I will accept.